# Wireless Repeater dropping packets

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, repeater

Ok so I went and bought a Linksys RE3000W Wifi repeater and followed the instructions, logged into the private Wifi which it creates to set it up connected to my main router and it went seamlessly.

The problem is when it's plugged in, the wifi anywhere in the house is garbage because a ping to 8.8.8.8 drops 4 packets every 8 packets. This is all of the time the repeater is plugged in.

I have tried two locations, one halfway between the router and the problem spot I had, and one at the furthest location from the router towards the bad spot which still has good signal/no drops and both had the exact same result. It's using the default setting of shadowing the routers SSID.

How can I fix this?